# How can I automatically adjust a range input by an API?

Tags: javascript, api, dynamic, slider, range

I am working on a slider to control a light fixture through an API.

If I want to know the status of the fixture I can request it from the API. This gives me back a value between 0 and 100. This value can change because someone is operating the lights in a different place. With JavaScript I can get this value in a text box by polling the API. But I can't get it done with the range slider. This one does not move. Can anyone help me get this done? And without submitting the page of course.

To complete my example below, I changed the API to a PHP file containing a simple code that actually does exactly the same thing.

**random.php**

`<?php echo rand(1, 100); ?>`

**My script**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
let url="http://127.0.0.1/random.php"
async function refreshh() {
    btn.disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("rangeInput").value = await(await fetch(url)).text();
    document.getElementById("amount").value = await(await fetch(url)).text();
    setTimeout(refreshh,3000);}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    refreshh();
});
</script>
<button hidden="" id="btn" onclick="refreshh()"> </button>
<input id="rangeInput" type="range"  min="0" max="100" oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value" />
<input id="amount" type="text"  oninput="rangeInput.value=amount.value" />
```

Output is that the "text" box works but the slider dosn't.

I hope someone can help me out.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out myself. The problem was that i cannot parse a text value to a slider it has to be a INT.

```js
let url="http://127.0.0.1/random.php";
async function refreshh() {
    btn.disabled = true;
    
    var result =  await(await fetch(url)).text();
    
    document.getElementById("rangeInput").value =  parseInt(result);
    document.getElementById("amount").value = result;
    
    setTimeout(refreshh,3000);}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    refreshh();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button hidden="" id="btn" onclick="refreshh()"> </button>
<input id="rangeInput" type="range"  min="0" max="100" oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value" />
<input id="amount" type="text"  oninput="rangeInput.value=amount.value" />
```